# Python: Need to add chosen filenames into an array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

The idea is simple: there is a directory with 2 or more files *.txt. My script should look in the directory and get filenames in order to copy them (if they exist) over the network.
As a Python newbie, I am facing problems which cannot resolve so far.
My code:

```
files = os.listdir('c:\\Python34\\');
for f in files:
    if f.endswith(".txt"):
    print(f)
```

This example returns 3 files:

```
LICENSE.txt
NEWS.txt
README.txt
```

Now I need to use every filename in order to do a SCP. The problem is that when I try to get the first filename with:

```
print(f[0])
```

I am receiving just the first letters from each file in the list:

```
L
N
R
```

How to add filenames to an array in order to use them later as a array elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a `list` of matching files names, then instead of using `os.listdir` and filtering, use `glob.glob` with a suitable pattern.

```
import glob
files = glob.glob('C:\\python34\\*.txt')
```

Then you can access `files[0]` etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the EXTEND method. So you say:

```
x = []
for f in files:
     if f endswith(".txt"):
           x.extend([f])
```

so it would be "adding" to the end of the list the file in which f is on.

Answer (score 0):

The array of files is `files`. In the loop, `f` is a single file name (a string) so `f[x]` gets the xth character of a filename. Do `files[0]` instead of `f[0]`.

Comment: Hi, with the change you suggested the result is: `DLLs
DLLs
DLLs`